# Is there a way to create a new tuple from an already exisiting tuple?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I need a way to generate a new tuple from another tuple.

```
std::string f1(int a)
{
    std::string b = "hello";
    return b;
}

float f2(std::string a)
{
    float b = 2.5f;
    return b;
}

int f3(float a)
{
    int b = 4;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::make_tuple(1, "a", 1.5f);
    //New tuple ---> std::tuple<std::string, float, int>(f1(1), f2("a"), f3(1.5));
    return 0;
}
```

This is just a minimal example of what I want to do. Is there a way of doing this in C++20, maybe using `std::tuple_cat`?

Comment: You can again `std::make_tuple` while using `std::get` to retrieve the respective elements from the first tuple `std::make_tuple(f1(std::get<0>(t1)), f2(std::get<1>(t1)), f3(std::get<2>(t1)))` or are you instead looking for a way to somehow "zip" tuple elements with a bunch of callables?

Comment: You can also use the exact code you have in your comment, unless your question is explicitly about how to read the values from your first tuple.

Comment: To answer the exact question asked: yes, there is a way to generate one tuple from another. But it is seems likely that this is not your real question; your real question is to take an arbitrarily-sized tuple, and equally-sized list of functions, then construct a new tuple by applying each function to the corresponding value from the old tuple. This template should work for a tuple of any size. Is my hunch correct?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to iterate over the first tuple and populate the new one

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::apply` to do this:

```
template<class Tuple, class... Fns>
auto tuple_transform(const Tuple& t, Fns... fns) {
  return std::apply([&](const auto&... args) {
    return std::tuple(fns(args)...);
  }, t);
}

auto t1 = std::make_tuple(1, "a", 1.5f);
auto t2 = tuple_transform(t1, f1, f2, f3);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rvb39h9E7)

Comment: Why not just use [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)?

Comment: @Mgetz To do what? We're not concatenating two tuples, we're changing one into a different one.